# How to define TcpListener for IP address

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcplistener

I have looked through some examples of `TcpListeners` and `TcpClients` , and in one example the server side TcpListener is declared like this

```
TcpListener listener = TcpListener.Create(8080);
listener.Start();
```

while on the other example it is like this

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener("78.78.78.120", 8080);
listener.Start();
```

Logically, the first method should use the default external IP address of the machine, where the second method you specify it explicitly.

So I am asking, what is the best way to define it? What will happen, if the server machine has dynamic IP address? Will it give error in the second method, if it's with dynamic IP?
And how will the client app connect to the server, if it does not know the IP address it is going to connect to (if it is dynamic)?

Answer (score 2):

> So I am asking, what is the best way to define it?

It depends on what behavior you want. That's why the API offers options: one size does not necessarily fit all.

On some machines there are multiple network adapters, and on some of those machines, it is desirable to limit a server's operation to some subset of those adapters, or even just one. In those cases, it's useful to provide a way to bind a socket to just one adapter.

In other cases, it's desirable for the server to listen on all available network adapters. In that case, using the default (or explicitly providing `IPAddress.Any`) is the "best way" (i.e. the only way).

> What will happen, if the server machine has dynamic IP address? Will it give error in the second method, if it's with dynamic IP?

If a correct IP address is provided, it will work fine. The fact that an IP address is dynamic does not preclude its use for a TCP listening socket.

If an incorrect IP address is provided (i.e. one that is not assigned to the machine), an error will occur.

> And how will the client app connect to the server, if it does not know the IP address it is going to connect to (if it is dynamic)?

There is no way for a networking client to connect to a networking server if it does not know the IP address.

However, the server having a dynamic IP address does not necessarily preclude the client knowing the address.

Even in the non-dynamic scenario, the most common way for a client to learn the IP address is to ask a DNS server, which resolves a textual name to the actual IP address. There are services that provide DNS name resolution for services or machines with dynamic IP addresses; they generally do this by using a fixed domain name, assigning the dynamically-addressed server to a subdomain.

For example, you might subscribe to service from noip.com, purchasing from them the domain `skaidar.noip.com`. Then the client would look up that name, and normal DNS resolution would translate that to your server's IP address. This type of service requires that your server or some related machine actively update the provider's name resolution information if and when the dynamically-assigned IP address changes; different providers have varying mechanisms to do that.

And of course, it is always possible for a human being to find out the dynamically-assigned IP address and then type that in directly for the client to use. :)